# How can I replace "S." (German abbreviation for page) with "Sp." (German abbreviation for column) in the Apacite-package for only two entries?

Tags: bibtex, bibliographies, naming, apa6

I've got a question concerning the replacement of "Sp" instead of "S" in a reference. For example, instead of getting

XXX, Y. (ABCD). YYY. In Y. XXX. (Ed.), FGAH. (A. ed., S. 01-03). VVVV: ZZZZ.

I would like to get the following reference:

XXX, Y. (ABCD). YYY. In Y. XXX. (Ed.), FGAH. (A. ed., Sp. 01-03). VVVV: ZZZZ.

How can I change the page-numbering from "S." to "Sp." for only two entries?

Here is a minimal example:

```
\documentclass{scrbook}
\pagestyle{plain} 
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
\author{XX} \title{YYY}
\begin{document} 
\maketitle 
\citep{Example1}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

The bib-file (test.bib) contains the following entry:

```
@inbook{Example1,
   author = {XXX, Y},
   title = {YYY},
   booktitle = {FGAH},
   editor = {XXX, Y},
   publisher = {ZZZZ},
   address = {VVVV},
   edition = {A.},
   pages = {01-03},
   year = {ABCD},
}
```

Thank you very much for any solution!

Comment: Please add a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. It will be much easier for us to reproduce your situation and find out what the issue is when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: O.k. I have finished my working example. Excuse my mistake, but I thought that this would not be necessary in this case.

Comment: In a strict sense this is still no [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228), because it incorporates too many packages, which are not needed to illustrate your problem. A further suggestion: Do us a favour and change your username to something more telling than "user2314393".

Comment: I'm sorry. Hopefully, it's better right now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Given that you appear to need to use "Sp." instead of "S." for only two entries, it doesn't seem to be a good use of your time to edit the bibliography style file `apacite.bst` to (a) create a new entry type called, say, `@inencyclopedia`, (b) create at least two new functions to generate the new look, and (c) rename the entries in question from `@inbook` to `@inencyclopedia`.

Instead, I would suggest you do the following:

- After creating the bibliography using `apacite` (by running LaTeX, BibTeX, and LaTeX twice more), open the file `\jobname.bbl` in your favorite text editor -- the one you're using for your .tex files will do fine -- and locate the `\bibitem` named `Example1` (or whatever the real key is).
- A few lines down, you'll see a line that looks like this:

  ```
  \BPG~01-03).
  ```

  Change it to

  ```
  Sp.~01--03).
  ```
- Repeat this for the other entry in question.
- Save the .bbl file and run LaTeX (but not BibTeX!) once more.

The only downside I can see to this approach is that you will have to remember to re-apply these edits after rerunning BibTeX.

Answer (score 1):

## Remarks

The only thing to do was changing two control sequences from `german.apc`. Note that this is global now. I don't see a way to distinguish between various citations.
Also you need to enclose it into `\AtBeginDocument{...}`, because `apacite` loads the file `german.apc` when `\begin{document}` is issued.

## Implementation

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{filecontents}
\begin{filecontents}{test.bib}
@inbook{Example1,
    author = {XXX, Y},
    title = {YYY},
    booktitle = {FGAH},
    editor = {XXX, Y},
    publisher = {ZZZZ},
    address = {VVVV},
    edition = {A.},
    pages = {01-03},
    year = {ABCD},
}
\end{filecontents}
\pagestyle{empty}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}
\usepackage[natbibapa]{apacite} 
% Needs to appear after \usepackage{apacite}
\AtBeginDocument{
    % Extracted from german.apc
    \renewcommand{\BPG}{Sp.\hbox{}}
    \renewcommand{\BPGS}{Sp.\hbox{}}
}
\begin{document} 
\citep{Example1}
\bibliographystyle{apacite}
\bibliography{test} 
\end{document}
```

## Output

> [image]

Comment: Thanks a lot, but I need this change only for two references (encyclopedia entries which were organized in columns and not in pages). Therefore, the remaining references must have "S." (=page).